# Permutation test: Exactness

Tags: statistical-significance, permutation-test

I am currently reading about permutation/randomization tests and have some difficulties to understand why they are exact. More precisely, I consider two groups of random variables with means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ and variances $\sigma^2_1$ and $\sigma^2_2$, which are assumed to be equal if  $ \mu_1 = \mu_2$ holds. 
To test the one-sided hypothesis $H_0: \mu_1 \leq \mu_2$ versus $H_1: \mu_1 > \mu_2$, I apply a permutation test with  the same test statistic as for a two sample t-test with unequal variances and unequal sample sizes. 
It was no big deal to prove and to understand that the level of significance of the permutation test is equal to $\alpha$ for $\mu_1 = \mu_2$. However, I don't understand why the level of significance is less than $\alpha$ for $ \mu_1 \leq \mu_2$!?
Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't see your question before. Something to consider: How do you work out the null-distribution of the test statistic in that case? Can you do it now?